# Exceeding Google Maps API request limit handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on creating handlers for Google Maps's possible errors.

One scenario I wanted to handle was the one where the number of requests made reaches the quota limit for the Google Maps JavaScript API.

When the request limit is reached, an error message covers the map. The error message reads: *This page can't load Google Maps correctly.*

There is also a message output to the console, *You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors*

This is all working as expected. Ideally, I would like to redirect the user to another page when the request limit is reached; however, I am totally stumped as to where I would handle this. Below is a code sample I use to load the Google Maps JavaScript API.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"

function useGoogleMapsApi() {
    const [api, setApi] = useState()
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if ((window as any).google) {
            setApi((window as any).google)
            return
        }
        
        const loader = new Loader({
            apiKey: 'MY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY',
            version: 'beta',
            libraries: ['places', 'geometry'],
        })
    
        loader
            .load()
            .then(() => {
                setApi((window as any).google)
            })
    }, [])
    
    return api
}

export default useGoogleMapsApi
```

Comment: There is no documented way to programmatically handle these. You have the possibility to setup quotas and alerts (notifications) though.

Comment: Please open a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814. There is some work that could be addressing this in the next year and having your specific use case documented would be beneficial!

Comment: @jpoehnelt I'll open a feature request. Thanks!

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'll take a look at setting up quotas and alerts. Another possible way I believe would be to parse the HTML and check for the attribute value, _This page can't load Google Maps correctly_ from the HTML. I could handle the return value of the check. I'll have to put some more thought into this approach, but doesn't seem ideal to me. Thanks!

Comment: Sure you could try that, but undocumented methods are always *not ideal* since if Google changes something, there is a risk that your code just stops working. Glad to see we have a GMP engineer on SO @jpoehnelt. If you open a feature request, you should link it here and link your question on the FR for followup.

Comment: @MrUpsidown That's a good point. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for your inputs.